# PHP/MySQL/TextArea problem

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to pull some html data from a mysql database to populate a text area.

I'm doing some tests with the home page content data and it only displays the last half of the html code I'm trying to select.

I can't wrap my head around all this problem!

Here is the textarea code I'm trying to use:

```
 <textarea style='width:600px;height:300px;' name='' value='<?php
                mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
                mysql_select_db("cgscms") or die(mysql_error());
                $sql = 'SELECT * FROM content where page_id ="1"';
                $result = mysql_query($sql);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
                    echo $row['content'];
                }

 ?>'></textarea>
```

Comment: Take the text area out of the equation. What do you get if you echo the content into a div or p tag? Furthermore, is the field in the db big enough to hold your content or is it truncated in the db?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Text area doesn't use Value. Try putting it between the textarea tags

```
 <textarea> put it here </textarea>
```

But another thing is if there are any quotes it will interfere with the quotes around value=""

Wrap the content result with htmlentities()

Comment: Just realised this was the case as soon as the question got migrated!
Thanks a lot mate!